# Nifi processors(publish and consume kafka) are not communicating with kafka on Ambari platform

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, apache-kafka-connect

I want to establish a communication channel between nifi and kafka.

1. Four processors in nifi(GenerateFlowFile->publishKafka) and (ConsumeKafka->logAttribute).
2. PublishKafka and ConsumeKafka are not communicating with Apache kafka(pictures are attached along with their errors).
3. Apache kafka security=PLAINTEXT
4. Kebros not installed.

I got stuck into this problem, nothing worked for me.

consumeKafka error

[image: X]

publish kafka error

[image: X]

Comment: Please don't add errors only as images because you can't search those and it's less helpful for others.

Comment: Please share the complete error log from `nifi-app.log`

Comment: o.a.n.p.kafka.pubsub.PublishKafka_0_10 PublishKafka_0_10[id=69adaef6-0166-1000-0000-00000bcebfb1] Failed to send all message for StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=6ab1fbc4-d184-4f9a-9eac-1efb8afc04a1,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1539371408618-1, container=default, section=1], offset=1576, length=16],offset=0,name=2434022322635860,size=8] to Kafka; routing to failure due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 5000 ms.: {}
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 5000 ms.

Comment: o.a.n.p.kafka.pubsub.ConsumeKafka_0_10 ConsumeKafka_0_10[id=69addbed-0166-1000-ffff-ffff9b13feb2] Was interrupted while trying to communicate with Kafka with lease org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.ConsumerPool$SimpleConsumerLease@7e7557a3. Will roll back session and discard any partially received data.

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman Both above mentioned comments are the errors produced by consume or publish kafka.Plz do suggest me the solution.